# Is it possible getting rowCount() from an AJAX request to use it in Pagination?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have a normal `$.post` **AJAX Request** that goes to this page

***ajax.php***

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['offset'])) { $offset = $_POST['offset']; } else { $offset = 0; }
$sql = "
SELECT a.name, b.fname, c.lname, d.mname FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table-b b ON a.id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN table-c c ON a.id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN table-d d ON a.id = d.id 
LIMIT $offset, 5
";
while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
        ...
}
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
$pages = ceil($total / 5);
$offset = ($page - 1) * 5;
?>
```

Right now after getting the `$total`, `$pages`, `$offset` what i tried is making the pagination inside `ajax.php` but i've been thrown at a stalement because i didn't know how to do that.

My last idea was getting the `$total`, `$pages`, `$offset` out with the `data` request from the first **AJAX** request, then Resend another **AJAX** request `onclicking` the `pagination` in the `main.php` page.

Is that the correct way, Is it possible to retreive PHP data from **AJAX** request? or there is another proper way to handle the `pagination` with **AJAX**.

Comment: Use `datatable` for easy manipulation.

Comment: you are not really returning anything. you are just setting php variables. best thing to do is add all the data you want to php array or object and echo the string return from json encoding the object

Comment: @JoshKisb so what i should do is `$limits=['total' => $total, 'pages' => $pages, 'offset' => $offset]; json_encode($limits);` then use it, Is it safe to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the required thing in an array like:

```
$arr = [
'total' = $stmt->rowCount();
'pages' = ceil($total / 5);
'offset' = ($page - 1) * 5;
// add as many variable as you want
];
```

and return it as a `json` object like:

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

On the JS side, parse it accordingly.

Comment: Is doing that is the safest and most proper way to handle Pagination with AJAX requests?

Comment: This is not only to handle Pagination with AJAX requests, this is the way to return multiple data on ajax call in any scenario